# not able to connect aws ec2 instance from windows machine with ipv6 address

Tags: amazon-ec2

When connected to internet, my machine get IPv6 ip address: 2401:4900:b8a:78f1:e8dd:8361:3c91:e1d3. I have allowed this ip in AWS firewall of EC2 instance to allow SSH traffic. But it does not connect.

It connects only when I allow all traffice in the AWS firewall of my EC2 instance.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Does your VPC support IPv6? Do you have a route in the route table for internet traffic on IPv6?

Comment: I don't know how to check it ?

Comment: Select your VPC it should have a value named `IPv6 CIDR`

Comment: It is blank. How can I enable it ?

Comment: Right click on your VPC, select edit CIDR range. Add an IPv6 range. Then in your route table(s) add a route to `::/0` to the IGW for public hosts (or an egress only gateway for private

Comment: I updated CIDR with IPv6 network.Routing tables of Subnets and ACLs have also been updated with IPv6. But it is still not connecting.

Comment: Hmm if you enable VPC flow logs perhaps you'd be able to see if it even gets inside your VPC